# Select words by js in search result

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I am using jQuery and creating now search. And i want to change all words that match of search.

For example:

i type in textbox "hello world", Script get all words "hello" and "world" on page and replace it on "`<b class="search_word">hello</b>`" and "`<b class="search_word">word</b>`".

Is it possible?

PS.

Search in div but div contains many other html elements.

now i am using this:

```
if ($("#search_input").val() != "") {
    var words = $("#search_input").val().split(/\s/g)
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var new_reg = new RegExp(words[i], 'gi');
        var replaced = $(".content_area").html().replace(new_reg, "<b class='searched_word'>"+words[i]+"</b>")
        $(".content_area").html(replaced);
    }
}
```

it works but tags...

if i search something like: "b class is the best class in School" it destroy page structure

Comment: You say "on page", do you mean in a single DIV or P element, or do really mean "anywhere in the whole of the HTML on the page? The first is easy, the latter more difficult. A listing of the relevant HTML would be useful for people to answer this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh ok, I understand, "onpage" search... hm....

this is a copy from [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)

```
var getTextNodesIn = (function() {
    function textNodeFilter() {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
    }

    return function(el) {
        var $el = $(el);
        return $el
            .contents()
            .filter(textNodeFilter)
            .add(
                $el
                   .find("*")
                   .contents()
                   .filter(textNodeFilter)
            );
    };
})();
```

you can now use

```
getTextNodesIn("body").each(function() {
 var txt = $(this).text();
 $(this).text(txt.replace(new RegExp(myWord,"g"), "<b>" + myWord + "</b>"));
});
```

Loop now through all of them and aply my filter previously written.

There where you found your word, you must select the whole text, and replace the found word with **found Word**

Comment: Aham, look at this  
var replaced = $(".content_area").html().replace(/Наверняка/, "!!!")
$(".content_area").html(replaced); 
How can i update this to replace not only first word but every words?

Comment: see my update please. Please do not use "html" since it will search html too, and don´t replace the whole contentarea with your new html,because you might destroy event binding. Always only text and always only replace by it´s parent container

Comment: something wrong in this $(this).text(txt.replace(new RegExp(myWord,"g"), "<b>" + myWord + "</b>")); line

Comment: As I said above, and so has Luke, without a listing of the relevant HTML it is difficult to help you!